# I take photo and from the same application I enter gallery to extract the image, how do I read the path of the extracted image?

Tags: android-studio, opencv

I am developing an application to take photo and draw it from the gallery, it captures well the photo, but if I enter gallery from the application does not show me the image but if I leave the app and enter gallery the photo appears, and when I re-enter gallery from the app it already shows me the image.
I want to know if there is a way for the image to appear to me right away but without having to leave the application.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final File ruta_fotos = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    final File file = new File(ruta_fotos, "DemoPicture.jpg");
    private Button boton;
    ImageView imagen;

```
public int cuenta=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imagen=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagemId);

    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTomaFoto);
    //Si no existe crea la carpeta donde se guardaran las fotos
    file.mkdirs();
    //accion para el boton

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String file = ruta_fotos + getCode() + ".jpg";
            File mi_foto = new File( file );
            try {
                mi_foto.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("ERROR ", "Error:" + ex);
            }
            //
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( mi_foto );
            //Abre la camara para tomar la foto
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //Guarda imagen
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            //Retorna a la actividad

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
        }

    });

}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private String getCode()
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date() );
    String photoCode = "pic_" + date;
    return photoCode;
}


public void Click(View view) {
    cargarImagen();
}
private void cargarImagen (){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/");
    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"seleccione a la aplicacion"),10);
    cuenta=1;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && cuenta==1){
        Uri path= data.getData();
        imagen.setImageURI(path);


    }
}
```

}
The next line I read the imegen that is predestined in the imageView but I want you to read the image that was extracted from gallery, how could I do that?
 Mat img = imread(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/colorballs.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

You have to add image through sendBroadcast, it will automatically show you in gallery means refresh your gallery. Put below code OnActivityResult after capturing image uri.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, path));
```